# Why does my Spinner reset when moved out of view?

Tags: java, android, view

I have a ListView of Spinners, using a custom adapter. When I run my code everything works fine except if I have more Spinners than fit on the screen. If I scroll down and show the last spinners, I can use them as intended but as soon as I scroll up and they go out of view, they reset to where the selected item is always the first one regardless of what item in the Spinner is selected.  . Why is this? I think its something to do with the getView method but I'm not sure how to save the selection so it is selected when it comes back into view again?

```
public class CustomPLNViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partLotNumbersArrayList;
private static ArrayList<String> partNames;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private Context myContext;

public CustomPLNViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results, ArrayList<String> parts){
    partLotNumbersArrayList = results;
    partNames = parts;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    myContext = context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_assembly_parts, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
        holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LotNumbers);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(partNames.get(position));        

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position));          
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //set the adapter to the spinnner
    holder.spinner.setAdapter(adp1);

    //if there is only one other part besides "" then set that as default part
    if(partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position).size() == 2){
        holder.spinner.setSelection(1);
    }   

    holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() == ""){
                Log.v("Spinner", "spinner value is blank");
                ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.assembly.addPart(new Part((String)holder.txtName.getText(), ""));
            }else{
                ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.assembly.addPart(new Part((String)holder.txtName.getText(), holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                Log.v("OnItemSelected", (String)holder.txtName.getText() + " : "+ holder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.assembly.addPart(new Part((String)holder.txtName.getText(), ""));
            Log.v("OnNothingSelected", (String)holder.txtName.getText());
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}   

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    Spinner spinner;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views in a `ListView` are meant to be recycled to limit the amount of memory they take up. The number of views created is equal to the number of list items that are visible on the screen. So when a list item is pushed off the screen and a new one appears, the one that is no longer visible is recycled to be used for the item that just scrolled into view.

You need to save the state of the spinner (if it was changed by the user) and restore that state in your `getView()` method. You can save the state in a simple array of objects that hold the state of the spinner (selected values, etc). Then in `getView()` you can check if you have any state saved for that spinner (indexed on its position in the list) and if it's there then set its values from the saved state.